# No error on updating deleted object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Rails executing update on deleted records.

I have a web app on ruby on rails in which I created some users and after that I opened the rails console and assigned U1 to one of my user let say last user then assigned the same User to U2. Then I run U1.destroy which executes successfully[image: you can check screenshot]
after that I updated the name of user through U2 and it returns me true [image: you can check screenshot] Although, user was destroyed from database when I checked it. My concern is rails should give me false as there was no object in database against that ID.

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE changes the values of the specified columns in all rows that satisfy the condition.
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Rails doesn't return `false` or raise an exception because the `UPDATE` is still a valid query in the database, even if no rows match the condition.  If you connect directly to your PostgreSQL database and run...

```sql
UPDATE users
SET name = 'test'
WHERE id = 123
```

...if `123` is an `id` that no longer exists, then the database will successfully execute the query and respond with:

```
UPDATE 0
```

If it is an `id` that still exists, the database will respond with:

```
UPDATE 1
```

This is similar to how Rails behaves if you use `update_all`.  If you were to run `update_all` on a record that no longer exists, you'd see something like:

```rb
User.where(id: 123).update_all(name: 'test')
 => 0
```

But if the record exists you'd see:

```rb
User.where(id: 123).update_all(name: 'test')
 => 1
```

No error will be raised.

The purpose of the Rails `update` and `update_all` methods is just to attempt to run an `UPDATE` query in the database. If there is a timing issue and the record no longer exists, that's not something that the database or Rails is designed to give warnings about.

Comment: but still the problem is there, rails didn't notify us about it how can we handle it. like if update method is returning us true and not updating anything in database. thern what is the purpose of returning true or false

Comment: There isn't really a problem though.  The purpose of these methods is to make an `UPDATE` query in SQL and that succeeded.  If there are timing issues in your app where one process could be working with a record that another just deleted, you will need to decide how you want to handle that.  Sometimes it's OK to say the delete was correct and the update should just be ignored.

Comment: The `true` / `false` for `update` is related to whether the object passed validations and that the query succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to double check that record exists before updating you can use `reload`

```rb
user.reload.update(name: "Some Name")
```

It will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if record with such `id` is absent